# Stuck with implementing permutations using recursion. Not getting any output

Tags: python, recursion, permutation

I want to write a function `permutations(route, cities)`. It should take a list (`cities`), append every possible permutations of the `cities` to the `route` list, and print each permutation in `route` on a new line. Every permutation ***must*** start with the first city, i.e. "Boston".

I am using recursion for this implementation, but can't get it to work.

```
def permutations(route, cities):

    def recurs(cities_temp):

        if len(cities_temp) == 0:
            return []
        elif len(cities_temp) == 1:
            return [cities_temp]
        else:
            route_temp = []

            for i in range(len(cities_temp)):
                x = cities_temp[i] #x is item i in the input list
                y = cities_temp[:i] + cities_temp[1+i:] #y is the remaining (everything but item i)

                for j in recurs(y):
                    route_temp.append([x] + j)
            return route_temp

    route = recurs(cities)

    print(' '.join([city_names[i] for i in route]))

city_names = ["Boston", "Seattle", "Chicago", "Dallas"]

permutations([0], list(range(1, len(city_names)))) #calling the permutations function
```

Can you all please take a look at it and let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What's the point of the ``route`` argument to ``permutations``? It seems redundant.

Comment: "but can't get it to work." What exactly does that mean? The title implies you get *no* output *at all*. Running the code loudly fails with ``TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list``, though.

Comment: I didn't look in detail, but I'm guessing `if len(cities_temp) == 0:
            return []
        elif len(cities_temp) == 1:
            return [cities_temp]` should instead be `if len(cities_temp) <= 1: return [cities_temp]`.

Comment: Removing everything from ``route = ...`` to ``... in route]))`` and replacing it with ``print(' '.join(city_names[i] for routes in recurs(cities) for i in route + routes))`` should "work", for a given definition of "work".

Comment: Also, why do you pass `list(range(1, len(city_names)))` and not directly `city_names`? Also note that `range(1, len(city_names))` has one fewer element than `city_names`. You probably want either `range(len(city_names))` or `range(1, len(city_names)+1)`.

Comment: There are 24 (4×3×2×1) [permutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) of four items taken four at a time. A "permutation" is an arrangement of the members of a set *into an ordered sequence* — i.e. the order matters. For that reason saying "Every permutation must start with the first city, i.e. 'Boston'" doesn't make sense.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, I made some changes to the code after I wrote the title for the post. It is indeed not compiling rather than not outputting anything. 

I agree that the `route` argument is redundant, but this is for an assignment and that was the instruction.

Comment: @Stef, thanks for the comments. This is for an assignment and the call for the function: `permutations([0], list(range(1, len(city_names))))` was already defined by the instructor. I now see that the elements should start with cities[1] since we want to always print "Boston" first. So it's the function's implementation I wrote wrong.

Comment: @martineau, that's right. But I am doing 6 permutations (3x2x1) for the other three cities with "Boston" always being the first one.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what's wrong with the code in your question, but it sounds like you may be [reinventing the wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinventing_the_wheel) since you can make use of the [itertools.permutations()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) function in the standard library to get them:

```
from itertools import permutations
from pprint import pprint

city_names = ["Boston", "Seattle", "Chicago", "Dallas"]

first, *rest = city_names  # Unpack.
routes = [(first, *permutation) for permutation in permutations(rest)]
pprint(routes)
```

Output:

```
[('Boston', 'Seattle', 'Chicago', 'Dallas'),
 ('Boston', 'Seattle', 'Dallas', 'Chicago'),
 ('Boston', 'Chicago', 'Seattle', 'Dallas'),
 ('Boston', 'Chicago', 'Dallas', 'Seattle'),
 ('Boston', 'Dallas', 'Seattle', 'Chicago'),
 ('Boston', 'Dallas', 'Chicago', 'Seattle')]
```

---

---

If you don't want or can't use `itertools` and you want or have to do it recursively, you first have to find out how that would work. In this case that would be something like this pseudo-code:

```
permutations[a, b, c, ...] = [
    a + permutations[b, c, ...], b + permutations[a, c, ..], ..., 
]
with the final term being:
    permutations[a] = [a]
```

Here's how to implement that in Python:

```
from pprint import pprint

def permutations(s):
    if len(s) <= 1:
        return [s]
    else:
        perms = []

    for e in permutations(s[:-1]):
        for i in range(len(e) + 1):
            perms.append(e[:i] + s[-1:] + e[i:])

    return perms


city_names = ["Boston", "Seattle", "Chicago", "Dallas"]
first, *rest = city_names  # Unpack.
routes = [(first, *permutation) for permutation in permutations(rest)]
pprint(routes)
```

Comment: Thanks for linking the permutations() documentation. I have been looking for it everywhere. It's good to see the algorithm. 

This is actually for an assignment, that's why use of itertools is discouraged.

Comment: Note that the sample implementation shown in the documentation isn't recursive — is that a requirement?

Answer (score 0):

I had ignored this exercise until I am in a better mindset but finally was able to solve it just like the instructor wished.

Here is the code. Thanks for all the responses to my original question.

```
portnames = ["PAN", "AMS", "CAS", "NYC", "HEL"]

def permutations(route, ports):
    n = len(ports) - 1

    def recursion(ports):
        if len(ports) == 1:
            return [ports]
        else:
            lst = []

            for i in range(len(ports)):
                x = [ports[i]]
                xs = ports[:i] + ports[i+1:]

                for j in recursion(xs):
                    if len(j) == n:
                        lst.append(route + x + j)
                    else:
                        lst.append(x + j)
        
        return lst
    

    for p in recursion(list(range(1, len(portnames)))):
        print(' '.join([portnames[i] for i in p]))
                    
 
    return recursion(ports)

permutations([0], list(range(1, len(portnames))))
```